# Sed Command to delete a line

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I want to remove a line which matches a specified pattern inside a test file. I want to use the command sed /'lines to match'/d inside a linux shell script. This is the code:

```
#Define input parameters
SCRIPT_NAME=$(basename $0)
PATHFILE=$1
NAMEFILE1=$2
NAMEFILE2=$3
HEADEREXPRESSION=$4
#Define input file
INPUTFILE1=$PATHFILE$NAMEFILE1
INPUTFILE2=$PATHFILE$NAMEFILE2
TEMPFILE=${INPUTFILE2}_TMP
touch $TEMPFILE
echo $INPUTFILE2
echo $HEADEREXPRESSION
echo $TEMPFILE 
#Remove header line from the second document
sed '/${HEADEREXPRESSION}/d' $INPUTFILE2 >> $TEMPFILE 
#rm -f $INPUTFILE2   
#echo $TEMPFILE >> $INPUTFILE1
```

In this code i want to remove from the first line in the test file that matches with the expression inside the variable HEADEREXPRESSION. Then the result will be placed tmp variable.
This is the text file:

> $SYSDATE$|PARENT_ELID|PARENT_ID_NUMBER|PARENT_REV|PARENT_LASTUPDATE_DATE|CHILD_ELID|CHILD_ID_NUMBER|CHILD_REV|CHILD_STATE|CHILD_LASTUPDATE_DATE|TSITEM|QUANTITY_DMS|OPTION_NAME|
>       2016/03/09 05:00:11|AQJ2DJTH|185273-13|NC|2016/03/09 01:56:14|AQJ2DJTL|185273-14|NC|RELEASED|2016/03/09 01:49:58|1|1||
>       2016/03/09 05:00:11|AQJ2DJTL|185273-14|NC|2016/03/09 01:49:58|AZEUQ03Z0047AR|185273-15|A|RELEASED|2003/01/15 09:46:18|1|1||
>       2016/03/09 05:00:11|C3PK881C6A5JK0|201200-142|M|2016/03/09 03:20:26|C3PK881BU135M0|201200-142EX|NC|RELEASED|2016/03/09 03:21:26|1|1||
>       2016/03/09 05:00:11|C3PK881C6A5JK0|201200-142|M|2016/03/09 03:20:26|C3PK881BU2HVF0|201200-142RL|NC|RELEASED|2014/07/23 09:35:14|1|1|1|
>       2016/03/09 05:00:11|BU9WPBTYLTYC60|3112535-02|NC|2016/03/09 04:58:35|BU9WPBTYMATB60|3112865-02|NC|CREATE|2016/02/26 02:40:14|101|1||
>       2016/03/09 05:00:11|BU9WPBTYLTYC60|3112535-02|NC|2016/03/09 04:58:35|DN09DMYM1ROY70|3112892|NC|RELEASED|2011/05/13 21:09:16|102|1||
>       2016/03/09 05:00:11|BU9WPBTYLTYC60|3112535-02|NC|2016/03/09 04:58:35|DN09DMYM2CRJP0|3112897|D2|RELEASED|2011/07/24 13:41:16|103|1||
>       2016/03/09 05:00:11|BU9WPBTYLTYC60|3112535-02|NC|2016/03/09 04:58:35|DN09DMYL210V60|1900169-1205|NC|RELEASED|2011/06/02 08:14:33|104|2||

I want to remove the first line using a pattern expression like:

```
$SYSDATE$|PARENT_ELID|PARENT_ID_NUMBER|PARENT_REV|PARENT_LASTUPDATE_DATE|CHILD_ELID|CHILD_ID_NUMBER|CHILD_REV|CHILD_STATE|CHILD_LASTUPDATE_DATE|TSITEM|QUANTITY_DMS|OPTION_NAME|
```

I invoke this script using this line command:

```
./delete_headeer.sh /wmextdata/scripts/DEV/primavera/SS_IPP_SOSLOAD/ SSP6_LINKS.TXT-20160309-000341 SSP6_LINKS.TXT-20160309_121000 "\$SYSDATE$|PARENT_ELID|PARENT_ID_NUMBER|PARENT_REV|PARENT_LASTUPDATE_DATE|CHILD_ELID|CHILD_ID_NUMBER|CHILD_REV|CHILD_STATE|CHILD_LASTUPDATE_DATE|TSITEM|QUANTITY_DMS|OPTION_NAME|"
```

However the first line that match with the pattern will not remove in the output file.
How can i fix the issue?

Comment: Reformat code for better readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following sed command to delete the pattern from a file

```
sed -i.bak "/$pattern/d" $FILE_NAME
```

Comment: This is correct.  Inside single quotes, the shell does not expand the variable value (so `sed '/${HEADEREXPRESSION}/d' …` will only delete a line containing a `$`, a `{`, `HEADEREXPRESSION` and a `}`) but using double quotes allows (requires) the shell to expand `${HEADEREXPRESSION}`, meaning that the right line will probably be deleted.